# Deserializing (Universal App) XML serialized with vb.net

Tags: xml, vb.net, win-universal-app, xmlserializer

I am serializing a class (PSD) using vb.net in a Windows Forms Application:

```
Dim objStreamWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter("e:\test.xml")
Dim x As New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(PSD.GetType)
x.Serialize(objStreamWriter, PSD)
objStreamWriter.Close()
```

I need to deserialze that class in a Windows Universal App.
This is my code so far:

```
Dim picker As Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker = New Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker
picker.ViewMode = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerViewMode.Thumbnail
picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".xml")
Dim File As Windows.Storage.StorageFile = Await picker.PickSingleFileAsync
Dim Fl = Await File.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read)
Dim inStream As Stream = Fl.AsStreamForRead()
Dim PSD As New PlatinaStammdaten
Dim serializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(List(Of PlatinaStammdaten)), New Type() {GetType(PlatinaStammdaten)})
PSD = serializer.Deserialize(inStream)
```

What I get is the error "There is an error in XML document (2, 2)."

This is the beginning of the generated XML-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Stammdaten xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Lose>
    <Los>
      <Name>Sonstige</Name>
      <KZ>000</KZ>
    </Los>
    <Los>
      <Name>LOS 1; Allgemein / Planung</Name>
      <KZ>110</KZ>
    </Los>
    ...
```

What error is in my code (writing or reading) that leads to that error?

Comment: To find the xml error use following menu : Project : Add New Item : XML file.  Then paste the xml file into window.  Error will show up like any compiler errors in teh Error List window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working now.
This is my deserializing code now:

```
Dim picker As Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker = New Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".xml")
        Dim File As Windows.Storage.StorageFile = Await picker.PickSingleFileAsync
        Dim Fl = Await File.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read)
        Dim FileZiel As Windows.Storage.StorageFile = Await File.CopyAsync(FolderZiel, File.Name, Windows.Storage.NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting)
        Dim Fl2 = Await FileZiel.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.ReadWrite)
        Dim inStream2 As Stream = Fl2.AsStreamForRead()
        Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(inStream2)
        Dim PSD As New PlatinaStammdaten
        Dim x As New XmlSerializer(PSD.GetType)
        PSD = x.Deserialize(sr)
        sr.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are try to deserialize a list into a single instance

Dim PSD As New PlatinaStammdaten
    Dim serializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(List(Of PlatinaStammdaten)), New Type() {GetType(PlatinaStammdaten)})
    PSD = serializer.Deserialize(inStream)

Try changing PSD to

```
Dim PSD As List(of PlatinaStammdaten)
```

since we cant see the full xml or the class you are putting the xml into it is hard to tell if you will encounter any other errors

Comment: You're on the right track, but OP is serializing a single PSD, not a list, so must deserialize to a single.

Comment: Yes, I have three classes: Ca, Cb and Cc (for this example). Before serializing I create three lists of these classes    Dim LA as list (Of Ca) and so on. My Class PSD consists of three properties (Type: List) and I only serialize one single instance of PSD - so it is only one object. My approach is, that I deserialize this class so I get three lists again

Answer (score 0):

The code below works

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Serialization
Imports System.IO

Module Module1
    Const FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"
    Sub Main()
        Dim xs As XmlSerializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(PlatinaStammdaten))
        Dim reader As XmlTextReader = New XmlTextReader(FILENAME)
        Dim PSD As PlatinaStammdaten = CType(xs.Deserialize(reader), PlatinaStammdaten)

    End Sub

End Module
<XmlRoot("Stammdaten")> _
Public Class PlatinaStammdaten
    Private m_lose As Lose
    <XmlElement("Lose")> _
    Public Property _lose As Lose
        Get
            Return m_lose
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Lose)
            m_lose = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

<Serializable(), XmlRoot("Lose")> _
Public Class Lose
    Private m_los As List(Of Los)
    <XmlElement("Los")> _
    Public Property _los As List(Of Los)
        Get
            Return m_los
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As List(Of Los))
            m_los = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class

<Serializable(), XmlRoot("Los")> _
Public Class Los
    Private m_Name As String
    <XmlElement("Name")> _
    Public Property name As String
        Get
            Return m_Name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_Name = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public m_KZ As Integer
    <XmlElement("KZ")> _
    Public Property KZ As Integer
        Get
            Return m_KZ
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            m_KZ = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class

'<Lose>
'  <Los>
'    <Name>Sonstige</Name>
'    <KZ>000</KZ>
'  </Los>
'  <Los>
'    <Name>LOS 1; Allgemein / Planung</Name>
'    <KZ>110</KZ>
'  </Los>
'</Lose>
```

Comment: I am trying to understand that. Where do you get XmlTextReader? In my windows universal app it is not recognized. (As I wrote: I serialize in a Windows Forms Application and deserialize in a Windows Universal App. And Lose is not a class in my code, but a List (Of Los). I need to put that list into a class?

Comment: I can't help with 3rd party code.  Just VS/Net code.  XmlTextReader is a Net Library class in System.Xml namespace.